# Flutter SetState Future

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart, mobile

**Widget Build Method:**

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (this.future!=null){
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: this.future,
        builder: (
            context,
            AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot,
            ) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return WaitScreen(title: 'Shopping List',);
          }
          return Scaffold(
              appBar: GFAppBar(
                  centerTitle: true,
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3F475F),
                  title: Text("Shopping Lists")),
              body: screen());
        },
      );

    }else{
      return Scaffold(
          appBar: GFAppBar(
              centerTitle: true,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF3F475F),
              title: Text("Shopping Lists")),
          body: screen());
    }
  }
```

**My button for changing Future variable in this widget:**

```
Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: InkWell(
              child: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  this.future = null;
                  this.future=_listHandler.deleteItemFromList(item, index);
                });;
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Problem is when I call this function for deleting some items. Set state works only one time. Second time it's not working. What is problem I did'nt get it.

Comment: so you mean that `build` method is not called for the second `onTap`? are you sure?

Comment: build method called for the second onTap but my future variable didn't changed. The same future function comes with the same results.

Comment: before `return FutureBuilder(` add `print('$future ${future.hashCode}')`

Comment: thank you now I know it's changing but I didn't understand the problem

Comment: i have no idea what you really mean... so is it the same `Future` or not?

Comment: It's not same future. HashCodes are different. I have ListHandler class and there is a function inside of it delete the item from the list. I want to show an indicator while waiting for the result. The problem is when I called first-time future builder works fine but if I call it the second time it's not working. Maybe ListHandler class is wrong.